# Distance between two radiobutton (horizontal radio group)

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to set distance between two radio buttons.

Like

[image]

How i can achieve this?  My code is like

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_your_order"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Delivery" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="PickUp" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Above code output looks like below picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this result with :
*using layout_weigth* and  *matching radio group to fill the screen*

```
<RadioGroup

    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_your_order"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Delivery" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PickUp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

**or**

even adding a dummy view that pushes both radio button to left end and right end like this:

```
<RadioGroup

    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_your_order"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Delivery" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PickUp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: why `TextView`? simply use `View`, it is lighter. Or `Spacer`, depending on your target

Comment: also with `weight=1`, use `width=0dp` instead of match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:gravity="right"` in the xml for the RadioButton which you want it to be right.
This should do want you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have done after changing my code to this one.

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/SkyBlue"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_your_order"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Delivery" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="PickUp" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change layout width in the first radio button, Put :
android:layout_width = "200dp"